# How do I suppress unwanted dollar and quote symbols when using "printf %q"?

Tags: bash, printf, quoting

I need to escape the newline characters in a public key in order to embed it within json output from within a bash script. What I want to do is this:

```
Little-Net:~ minfrin$ [escape-it-somehow] server.pub"
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAqczXmXuynhalcmzP7ebV\nd7RYLLKJlGLT3OGL5VMnttvPRWoYGueseXnwlHKOcEYv0ZdSVi+e+yWK0lVgARQ9\nkNdumatV9h1S7IHC8fFexuz32Pu7piZlIcsRR+wSWXyA53KPT3NahlLqUGzQ66WX\nGqNmvcJjY0YcaPYjDsueTuQK3wogGOYrVetI33nVX/1ckBbtjgAjf8Bpieb2SQ1Z\nJYt+iBE4h7shUrRT9kT7+8BpGuZgUTVYFSxRw9r6TaFrLyaImRCELTqrxILSHWcz\nJtYBzyYFjYzENNn5L4fcrDFIId5oNil3ZaDtDFNdekdyOdirSHC3J7+aHbYKnC8a\nWwIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

I have tried to use the bash printf function, but for reasons I do not understand the output is surrounded by a dollar and quote characters like so:

```
Little-Net:~ minfrin$ printf %q "$(cat server.pub)"
$'-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAqczXmXuynhalcmzP7ebV\nd7RYLLKJlGLT3OGL5VMnttvPRWoYGueseXnwlHKOcEYv0ZdSVi+e+yWK0lVgARQ9\nkNdumatV9h1S7IHC8fFexuz32Pu7piZlIcsRR+wSWXyA53KPT3NahlLqUGzQ66WX\nGqNmvcJjY0YcaPYjDsueTuQK3wogGOYrVetI33nVX/1ckBbtjgAjf8Bpieb2SQ1Z\nJYt+iBE4h7shUrRT9kT7+8BpGuZgUTVYFSxRw9r6TaFrLyaImRCELTqrxILSHWcz\nJtYBzyYFjYzENNn5L4fcrDFIId5oNil3ZaDtDFNdekdyOdirSHC3J7+aHbYKnC8a\nWwIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----'
```

My question is, why are the dollar and the quote characters added by printf? How do I stop printf from adding the dollar and quote symbols? Is there another technique I should be using instead of printf to escape a newline character?

This is bash as provided by MacOSX 10.10.5. I get the same result from bash as supplied by CentOS6.

Comment: `minfrin$` is this part of your prompt ?

Comment: `%q` prints it as "shell quoted", so that it can be passed as an unaffected literal into other commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `awk` for escaping:

```
awk -vRS="\n" -vORS="\\\n" '1' server.pub
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a JSON tool to do JSON escaping. For example, using [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
my_key="-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAqczXmXuynhalcmzP7ebV\nd7RYLLKJlGLT3OGL5VMnttvPRWoYGueseXnwlHKOcEYv0ZdSVi+e+yWK0lVgARQ9\nkNdumatV9h1S7IHC8fFexuz32Pu7piZlIcsRR+wSWXyA53KPT3NahlLqUGzQ66WX\nGqNmvcJjY0YcaPYjDsueTuQK3wogGOYrVetI33nVX/1ckBbtjgAjf8Bpieb2SQ1Z\nJYt+iBE4h7shUrRT9kT7+8BpGuZgUTVYFSxRw9r6TaFrLyaImRCELTqrxILSHWcz\nJtYBzyYFjYzENNn5L4fcrDFIId5oNil3ZaDtDFNdekdyOdirSHC3J7+aHbYKnC8a\nWwIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"

jq -n --arg pkey "$my_key" '{publickey: $pkey}'
```

The `--arg` option sets a `jq` variable named `pkey` to the value stored in the shell variable `my_key`. The `jq` script then outputs a simple object with one key, `public_key`, whose value is the contents of `pkey`.

Or, let `jq` read directly from the file:

```
jq -R '{publickey: .}' < server.pub
```

The `-R` option tells `jq` to read its input as raw text, not as JSON to be parsed. The `.` inside the object represents the input to the filter, so the contents of the file are used as the value of `publickey`.

Comment: The question related specifically to bash. Just to clarify - we need a portable solution if possible.

Comment: What do you mean by portable? That usually means something using tools specified by POSIX, and POSIX doesn't specify anything suitable for dealing with JSON.